# who to pass index of a loop (for loop) in python

Tags: python-3.x

I put this pre defined part in my python code, the aim of code is to get last 2 digits and put it on cluster list based on the predefined logic in cluster (index as list[1] and variable of index in cluster(2).
Now I have problem with my loop that says there are indentation error.

```
def find_min(matrix=[]):
    i,j=0,0
    min1=[1000,0,0]
    while i <len(matrix):
        while j <len(matrix):
            if matrix[i][j] != 0:
                if min1[0]>matrix[i][j]:
                    min1[0]=matrix[i][j]
                    min1[1]=i
                    min1[2]=j
            j+=1
        j=0    
        i+=1
    return min1[1:]

def check_min(variable,list2=[]):
    i=0
    min=1000
    list3=list2[:]
    result=0
    while i<len(list3):
        if variable-list3[i]>0:
            result=variable-list3[i]
            list3[i]=result
        else:
            result=list3[i]-variable
            list3[i]=result
        i+=1
    i=0
    while i<len(list3):
        if min>list3[i]:
            min=list3[i]
        i+=1
    return min

def grouped(variable,cluster=[]):
    cluster1=cluster[:]
    k=0
    list3=[]
    index=0
    while k<3:
        index=k
        if variable in cluster1[index]:
            list3.append(1)
            list3.append(cluster[index])
            return list1
        else:
            continue
        K+=1
    return [0,-1]




list1=[10,11,30,40,70,80]

cluster=[[0,1][10,11],[2,3],[30,40],[],[]]
```

Then I want to have this loop to work but it shows me idiot errors!

```
w, h = len(list1), len(list1)
matrix = [[None for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
i,j,z=0,0,0
check=0
check2=0
k,e=0,0
flag1=0
index1,index2=0,0
index_i=0
index_j=0
index_cluster_i=0
index_cluster_j=0
temp1=[]
while i <len(list1):
    index1=i
    while j <len(list1):
        index2=j
        #if i is in a cluster already
        temp1=grouped(index1,cluster)
        index_i=temp1[0]
        index_cluster_i=temp1[1]
        #if j is in a cluster already
        temp1=grouped(index2,cluster)
        index_j=temp1[0]
        index_cluster_j=temp1[1]

        if(i>j):
            matrix[i][j]=0
        elif (index_i==1 and index_j==1):
            matrix[i][j]=0
        elif(index_i==1 and index_j==0):
            matrix[i][j]=check_min(list1[j],cluster[index_cluster_i])
        elif(index_i==0 and index_j==0):
            if list1[i]>list1[j]:
                matrix[i][j]=list1[i]-list1[j]
            else:
                 matrix[i][j]=list1[j]-list1[i]
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

error is:

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: You got additional space after `else:` in the end of second code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is for improper indentations align each block under its statement.
Like:

```
if i === True:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I have written a edit note that the editor isn't applying the newline. It looks fine when editing.